# Sqoop import fetching more records from source

Tags: sqoop

I recently encountered an issue with SQOOP import.

When I mention the following :

```
--num-mappers 10 SQOOP import fetches 10x records
--num-mappers 15 SQOOP import fetches 15x records
--num-mappers 1 SQOOP import fetches exact records
```

for the same select query.

the select query contains a LEFT outer join which when ran on the DB returns x records, which is what I am trying to retrieve.

The query is :

```
SELECT table1.*,table2.* from table1 left outer join table2 on
(table1.tab1_id = table2.tab2_id);
```

As tab2_id is a PK for table2 i am using the same for the --split-by clause.

But I am unable to understand why the SQOOP returns different #records when different #mappers are specified

Comment: Primary key you are using is a increasing incremental number ? / INT ?

Comment: @roh Yes the Primary key used is an integer column.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the sql query, that was intermediately submitted to the SQOOP job, was not yielding correct result set.

Reason::
The SQOOP command looked like ::

```
sqoop import --connect <JDBC connection string> -m 10 --hive-drop-import- 
delims --fields-terminated-by '\001' --fetch-size=10000 --split-by <PK
column> --query "SELECT table1.*,table2.* from table1 left outer join
table2 on (table1.tab1_id = table2.tab2_id) AND \$CONDITIONS"
```

And this $CONDITIONS is internally replaced by the lower/upper boundary values.

And as there is no where condition in the query, this $CONDITIONS block is having no effect on the splitting of the data to mappers, resulting in delegating the entire data to all the mappers whichever is being spawned.